# It is possible to develop a facebook application using PhoneGap?

Tags: facebook, html, mobile, cordova

Basically, I'm doing some thesis. 
A facebook application that is playable on Mobile Devices.

The idea is, 
1. I'll create an application.
2. It will be playable on Facebook. http://apps.facebook.com/[name]
3. It will be accessible and playable on Mobile Web Browser through http://apps.facebook.com/[name]

If you have any idea on developing an application on facebook that is playable on Mobile Web Browser as well. It will be much appreciated if you shared it with me.

Things that I've researched so far:
1. Not all flash game are playable on Mobile Devices. 
      *Flash-lite can't handle all apps, like Farmville.*
2. Server-side games work pretty well.  *Mafia Wars and the like..*

Solution I think so far:
HTML5 Canvas.

Problem: 
I don't know what kind of framework that will work pretty well for the Desktop browser and Mobile Web Browser as well.

Thanks for reading.. ><

Comment: Flash won't work at all on iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run game or any other mobile web app on url http://apps.facebook.com/[name] because facebook will load you app in iframe and currenty facebook layout when displaying canvas apps is't made for phones only desktop.

I had the same problem recentry but it wasn't the game but some forum like app. My solution was to have the mobile app on domain myapp.com and when it's load I detect if device is mobile or desktop.

If it's a desktop browser I redirect user to fb canvas app on http://apps.facebook.com/name which runs the same app from the same domain myapp.com but uses different visual templates for displaying it self.

And if it's a mobile phone I leave user on myapp.com and display app with visual templates for mobile version.

So I have same app with two visual interfaces, one for desktop that runs inside facebook and one on mobile. And mobile version uses facebook connect to login user. Database in background is the same and basically everything is the same except interface.

And it work really well.